# When creating user accounts using C#, UPN logon doesn't work while sAMAccountName works

Tags: active-directory, login, windows

I have created accounts with C# on 2008 R2 which have a `sAMAccountName` and a `user principal name`. I can log on with the `sAMAccountName` (or explicitly `DOMAIN\sAMAccountName`), but not with the `UPN`.

**Another manually created account works fine with UPN or sAMAccountName.**

```
private static SecurityIdentifier everyoneSid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
private static SecurityIdentifier selfSid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.SelfSid, null);
private static Guid changePasswordGuid = new Guid("{AB721A53-1E2F-11D0-9819-00AA0040529B}");
private static ActiveDirectoryAccessRule allowEveryone = new ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(everyoneSid, ActiveDirectoryRights.ExtendedRight, AccessControlType.Allow, changePasswordGuid);
private static ActiveDirectoryAccessRule allowSelf = new ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(selfSid, ActiveDirectoryRights.ExtendedRight, AccessControlType.Allow, changePasswordGuid);
private static ActiveDirectoryAccessRule denyEveryone = new ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(everyoneSid, ActiveDirectoryRights.ExtendedRight, AccessControlType.Deny, changePasswordGuid);
private static ActiveDirectoryAccessRule denySelf = new ActiveDirectoryAccessRule(selfSid, ActiveDirectoryRights.ExtendedRight, AccessControlType.Deny, changePasswordGuid);

public static void CreateUserAccount(string title, string firstName, string lastName, string samaccountname, string login, string password, string uid, string description, bool pupil)
{
    string oGUID = string.Empty;

    string ldapPath = "LDAP://OU=Pupils,DC=domain,DC=foo";

    using (DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath))
        using (DirectoryEntry newUser = dirEntry.Children.Add(string.Format("CN={0} {1} {2}", lastName, firstName, uid), "user"))
        {
            newUser.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = uid;
            newUser.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = login + "@" + Domain.GetCurrentDomain();
            newUser.Properties["description"].Value = "Pupil";
            newUser.Properties["personalTitle"].Value = title;
            newUser.Properties["givenName"].Value = firstName;
            newUser.Properties["sn"].Value = lastName;
            newUser.Properties["displayName"].Value = string.Format("{0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
            newUser.Properties["employeeID"].Value = uid;
            newUser.Properties["employeeType"].Value = "Pupil";
            newUser.Properties["employeeNumber"].Value = password;
            newUser.Properties["businessCategory"].Value = "Test";
            newUser.CommitChanges();
            oGUID = newUser.Guid.ToString();

            newUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = ADS_UF_NORMAL_ACCOUNT | ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD;

            ActiveDirectorySecurity userSecurity = newUser.ObjectSecurity;

            // Remove any existing rule that gives "everyone" the change password right.
            userSecurity.RemoveAccessRuleSpecific(allowEveryone);
            // Add a new access rule to deny "everyone" the change password right.
            userSecurity.AddAccessRule(denyEveryone);
            // Remove any existing rule that gives "self" the change password right.
            userSecurity.RemoveAccessRuleSpecific(allowSelf);
            // Add a new access rule to deny "self" the change password right.
            userSecurity.AddAccessRule(denySelf);

            newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { password });

            newUser.CommitChanges();
        }           
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that the UPN the users are trying to use are correct?

Comment: I edited my question because I failed to explain that account where created using C#.

Answer (score 1):

Users are allowed to log in with their UPN by default, and I know of no way to disable this.

Usually when I see this problem, what is actually happening is that the server can't contact the DC for some reason, and is using cached credentials.  The caching mechanism is not very smart, and matches the entered username as a string, so users who previously entered their unqualified account name can continue to do so, but if they attempt to qualify it they will get logon failures.

If this is not happening you likely have some kind of issue with your DCs, but without the actual error you are getting (and possibly a look at the event log on the system and the DC servicing the logon) it's impossible to say.

Comment: My bad, it's apparently not a UPN-related problem, but an account creation method. I edited my question.